# data-* attributes does not displaying in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor to allow all types of content to store in my database.  Some HTML content has `data-*` attributes used for storing values.  When I save the HTML content from the CKEditor by fetching the value using `$(".ckeditor").val()`, it stores the value in database very well.  However when I fetch ckeditor data from the database and set the value in CKEditor it does not show the `data-*` attributes in neither source mode nor HTML mode. Nevertheless in the database, I can see the `data-*` attributes.

I'm using `CKEditor 4.5.1` version.

In my config file I have set:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
```

Can anyone help me on this issues, I have looked into many solutions and it should be working.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392564/how-to-configure-ckeditor-so-it-keeps-data-attributes-instead-of-removing-them

Comment: There is on workaround is either remove href="#" or add some text after # like this href="#sometext". This is working but that's not a solution.

Comment: After you fetch the value from the database, do a an `alert` of the value or just echo it in the page outside CKEditor and view the page source code to make sure that even though you see the data-* attributes in the database, they arrive unchanged in your page.